# Android service that can interact with other apps

Tags: android, service, ipc

So I'm building an app that has the ability to run in the background and can potentially interact with other components of the OS.

Let's say you're navigating through your file manager, my app would want to add an additional action to what you can normally do with the file manager. The same thing can happen when say you're browsing with a browser, you have one additional action you can do. I've been looking at intentservices and bound services.

Can any body tell me if this is doable? Yes? No? A one line explanation would be great as well.

Comment: Please explain, **completely and precisely**, what "add an additional action" means. Do you mean that when the user taps on an item in a file manager, that you want to appear in the chooser that appears for the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` the file manager invokes?

Comment: Yes that would be it. To have an additional item on the list of things you can choose from. Say for example, in my case, when I select a file in my phone's file manager, a view pops-out where I can choose which app I want to complete that action with. I want to add an additional option on that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with services. This has everything to do with having an `<intent-filter>` on an `<activity>` that identifies what file types you support for various `Intent` actions, like `ACTION_VIEW`. Well-written apps that launch such an `Intent` will either:

- use the system chooser, in which case you will appear in the option in that chooser, or
- use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to build their own "chooser", and you will appear in its UI

Note, though, that not all apps are well-written. Some morons will only support a fixed set of apps, and there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: So it's doable to a certain extent. Thanks that's all I needed to know.